# How to default to paragraphs when using designMode

Tags: designmode, paragraphs

I'm trying to create a very simple and light wysiwyg editor using designMode/execCommand, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    wysiFrame.document.designMode = 'On';
});
<iframe name="wysiFrame" id="wysiFrame"></iframe>
```

When I enter text in the iframe it is not wrapped in any tags. When I hit return the new line is wrapped in a div, eg:

```
here's my bit of text
<div>and this is the text after hitting return</div>
```

If I add:

```
$('#wysiFrame').contents().find("body").append('<p>Select me and type</p>');
```

and then select the text and over type the tags are added (in Chrome at least) as expected, new paragraphs and line breaks.

I tried:

```
$('#wysiFrame').contents().find("body").append('<p></p>');
```

But that gave me:

```
My typed text
<p></p>
```

Is there a way to wrap entered text within paragraph tags? I have trawled online but have only been able to find reference to preventing line breaks in favour of paragraph tags.
All help, suggestions and ideas welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get something together that although not elegant may be useful to others looking for a no-fuss, simple (dirty!) solution. In my 'designMode = 'on' function I added:

```
$('#wysiFrame').contents().find("body").append('<p>&nbsp;</P>');
```

When you click in the iFrame the insertion point lands between the space and the closing paragraph tag, just a little clean up needed server-side. Tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, seems to work reliably in all.
Any other suggestions out there?